# Excluding subdirectories from SQL Server selection

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to use `SQL Server` to select all from a list of files that do not contain subdirectories. Below is a sample query and my list in database. My current query does not exclude the subdirectories.

```
SELECT myColumn FROM myTable WHERE CHARINDEX( '\groups\ss', myColumn ) > 0
```

Output:

```
myColumn
\groups\ss\default.asp
\groups\ss\about.asp
\groups\ss\BMSS\
\groups\ss\TEP\about.asp
\groups\ss\SCSS\
\groups\ss\RSESS\more\about.asp
\groups\ss\RASS\
\groups\ss\OTSS\a\b\c\def\about.asp
\groups\ss\OPHSS\
\groups\ss\NTSS\
```

I would like the returned results to only be the `default.asp` page and the `about.asp` page **IN THE MAIN SS** directory. I do not know the names of files in advance, so I can't type out `about.asp`.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I just add a '\' surrounded by wildcard characters in this addition below:

AND myColumn NOT LIKE '\groups\ss\%\%'

Comment: Tnis will return `\groups\ss\BMSS`, won't it?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri you are correct. My sample data was incorrect. I've added the additional backslash to sample data entires.